# DirectShow webcam preview inside Firebreath plugin, not showing the preview after I refresh the webpage

Tags: directshow, firebreath

I created a sample application to show the webcam preview using DirectShow inside the firebreath plugin window. It is working fine when I load the webpage first time, but is it not  working after I navigate to another pages and return back to the plugin page. It is also not working after I refresh the webpage. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something isn't getting cleaned up properly or possibly you're using some global resources that are getting shared between plugin instances that doesn't get completely reset.

Remember that a plugin isn't unloaded between instances, so if you use any global/static variables the process is not shut down between instances of the plugin; this causes trouble for a lot of libraries used in a plugin that were written for an application, as most applications that use directshow figure the process will be closed before anything is used again and thus don't clean up after themselves completely.

Anyway, with what info you've given us that's my best guess. It might not be something obvious -- it could be something inside directshow.

Comment: Removed the filters from the graph at the window dettached event and that fixed the issue. Thanks